# Postgres self-update query doesn't update all records

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I've run a query which looks like this

```sql
update my_table
set column1 = 1
where id in (select id from my_table where column1 = 2 and column2 = 'value')
```

after update of this table I run same select query from `where` statement and I get some records. Note that update change value of `column1` which is used if `select` filter. Does it possible that not all records was update because of this query?

If this is matter that table volume is 10M+. There are only few thousands of records that should be update by this query

PS: I know that query might be simpler(without separate `select`) but this is what we have

Comment: The UPDATE will change all rows that qualify based on the WHERE clause. The rows that will be updated are evaluated _before_ anything is changed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In my case records were exist before update query and was not update during/after update query

Comment: That's hard to believe. You will need to provide a complete and self-contained test case that reproduces this situation. I would assume your data doesn't contain the values you think it does and thus the WHERE clause selects rows you do not expect.

Comment: Did you have other data changing queries running against that table at the same time?